# How to create an alias that will open file in Brackets?

Tags: command-line, alias

New to this whole Linux thing, and creating alias' in Mac seemed a little easier!

Anyway, I'm trying to create an alias that will open the desired file within Brackets, or Sublime... etc.

I don't want to use gedit, prefer brackets for coding etc. Can't seem to find anything that specifically helps with this.

I.E in terminal:

```
codeit myFile.ext
```

codeit being almost the same functionality as gedit but opening desired file in Brackets/Sublime Text.

Comment: So you want to have a command `codeit` that takes a filename as parameter and opens it with a specific IDE, right ? You might want to look into adding a bash function to your `.bashrc` file , because aliases cannot take parameters.  [Refer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7131683/3701431)

Comment: I don't understand. Presumably `brackets` is a program and I know that Sublime text is. Why don't you jusrt run `brackets yourfile.txt`? What do you want an alias for? Are you trying to change the default editor that is opened when you double click a text file?

Comment: Clearly I dont know linux at all.. lol Thanks for the help guys, the program file.ext is what I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, your first step should be to install `brackets`. To do this, have a look at this [tutorial.](http://itsfoss.com/install-brackets-ubuntu/)

Here are the commands you need:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/brackets
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brackets
```

Then you should be able to open a file by typing `brackets myFile.txt` in your terminal.

---

As your talking about "alias" in your question:

You can define an alias like `alias newCommand='command to execute'`. So using `alias gedit='brackets'` will run `brackets myFile.txt` when you typed `gedit myFile.txt`. To make this permanent, you have to add the line to your `.bashrc`.